# Find the length of minimum sublist of a given list that contains all the numbers from the list

Tags: algorithm

Given an Array A[] = {7,3,7,3,1,2,3,4,1}. The distinct numbers in the Array are 1,2,3,4,7
I want to find the length of the contiguous subsequence of numbers  in A, which contains 
all these numbers, so in the above, for example, A will have 6. The minimum subsequence - 7,3,1,2,3,4 is of length 6 which contains all the numbers 1,2,3,4,7 
One approach is to see if, for all pairs of the index (i,j), the numbers from A[i] to A[j] contain all the numbers from the A. But this will yield an O(n^2) algorithm. Could there be an efficient way 
 to do this?

Comment: _"[7,3,1,2,3,4] is of length 6 which contains all the numbers [1,2,3,4,7]"_ - Why  `[7,3,1,2,3,4]`  contain 3, Two times?

Comment: Can you please share your "brute force"  `O(n^2)` approach?

Comment: @Nur The requirement is to contain all the different numbers in a contiguous fragment of the array. It doesn't matter if it repeats. The fragment length should be minimum

Comment: as @Daniel Hao mention, you should share your code, Sometime code explain more words, as it would help us to understand your intention

Comment: The language in the question is a bit iffy, but I'm guessing from "sublist" in the title and "contiguous subsequence" in the description, the op is looking for the *smallest length subarray that contains all unique numbers in `A`*. If my interpretation of the problem is correct, then a hint is that you can solve this via a greedy approach in linear time.